# Getting started with Owl Carousel in Fiddle

Tags: jsfiddle, owl-carousel

I wanted to get started toying around with Owl Carousel, and just tried cutting and pasting the contents of [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/s10bgckL/2/) over to [my own fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/randomengineer/2pabreox/8/), and adding the required three resources. However, the carousel isn't executing, and I'm just getting the images one after another in a table. I recognize that the typical way to modify a fiddle is to fork it, but I want to know what I'm doing wrong when starting my own fiddle.

Clearly I'm missing something basic here, a basic Fiddle getting started/include issue. What is it?

[image]

Pasting irrelevant code here because Stack Overflow has new rules that won't let me post a fiddle link without some code in the question:

```
<div id="owl-demo">
    <div class="item">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/50x50" alt="Owl Image" />
    </div>
    <div class="item">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/50x50" alt="Owl Image" />
    </div>
    <div class="item">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/50x50" alt="Owl Image" />
    </div>
    <div class="item">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/50x50" alt="Owl Image" />
    </div>
    <div class="item">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/50x50" alt="Owl Image" />
    </div>
    <div class="item">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/50x50" alt="Owl Image" />
    </div>
    <div class="item">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/50x50" alt="Owl Image" />
    </div>
    <div class="item">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/50x50" alt="Owl Image" />
    </div>
</div>
```